# CosmosDb scale down partitions after data purge

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have a cosmos database with 7 containers, 8 partitions, and 20k autoscale shared RU so we have 2,500 RU throughput per partition.

```
20k / 8 = 2,500 RU/s throughput
```

Its always been 20k autoscale so I am not sure how we got 8 partitions but we do. We removed a container in the db that was getting 95% of the traffic so naturally we scaled the RU down to 5k. The problem is now we are limited to 625 RU per partition throughput.

```
5k / 8 = 625 RU/s
```

This data could all be served from one partition and we could leverage all 5k RU. Is there a way to address this other than move all the data to a new instance?

Comment: I just noticed that you are using database provisioned throughput so deleted my answer as I'm not as clear on that. Can you confirm how many collections there are in the database too? Not sure if that has a bearing on partition count

Comment: You cannot scale-in the number of physical partitions; you'd need to migrate to a new collection if you wanted to start with a lower number of physical partitions. I answered this near-identical question elsewhere - I'll mark this one as a duplicate so you can see the details of the answer there...